# How to give plotlines text styles on opposite side instead of default

Tags: highcharts

I have created a chart using Highcharts. Drawn to plot lines on X Axis. I would like to display the plot line on opposite side instead of the default

My Code is

```
plotLines: [{
                value: pur_time,
                width: 2 ,
                color: '#656568',
                dashStyle: 'dash',
                id: 'plotline',
                label: {
                          text: 'Purchase deadline',
                          style: {
                            color: '#656568',
                            fontWeight: 'bold'
                          }
                        }
            },{
                value: exp_time,
                width: 2 ,
                color: '#A28F29',
                id: 'plotline1',
                label: {
                          text: 'Expiration time',
                          opposite: true,
                          style: {
                            color: '#686A3B',
                            fontWeight: 'bold'
                          }
                        }
            }]
```

Here is the sample what i actually gets

[image]

How am expecting to look like is

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try the `rotation` attribute for your plot line labels (see http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.plotLines.label.rotation).

I modified the demo fiddle in API documentation to match what you're looking to do: http://jsfiddle.net/brightmatrix/kuyy5p6f/

```
          label: {
            text: 'Plot line',
            verticalAlign: 'middle',
            textAlign: 'center',
            rotation: 270,
            x: -5
          }
```

In this case, I set `rotation` to `270` to flip it over, and set an `x` value of `-5` to push it out to the left.

I hope this is helpful!